# Inner Join of three different Tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working in Oracle APEX. I want to make a report from three different tables **(Patient, History, Treatment)** through `INNER JOIN` . Tables are as fallows.

> PATIENT (Par_Id(Pk),Pat_Name,Pat_Gender)

> HISTORY (His_Id(Pk),Pat_id(Fk),Treated_By)

and

> Treatment (
> Treat_Id,
> His_id(Fk),Pat_id(Fk)
> ,Treat_Type
> ,Charges)

How I am going to display all the mentioned columns of the three Tables in
the report.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a worthwhile endeavour you described... so what's the question?

Comment: ... and you tagged it with mysql...

Comment: you need all column from three table and than you accepted answer which is having column specific, modify your question accordily..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should always specify the columns to return, especially as the tables contain identical column names

```
SELECT p.Par_Id, p.Pat_Name, p.Pat_Gender,
    h.His_Id, h.Treated_By,
    t.Treat_Id, t.Treat_Type, t.Charges
FROM Patient p 
INNER JOIN History h 
    ON p.PAR_ID = h.PAT_ID
INNER JOIN Treatment t
    ON h.HIS_ID = t.HIS_ID AND p.PAR_ID = h.PAT_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM Patient p 
    INNER JOIN History h 
        ON p.PAR_ID = h.PAT_ID
    INNER JOIN Treatment t
        ON h.HIS_ID = t.HIS_ID AND p.PAR_ID = h.PAT_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select * from 
PATIENT  inner join HISTORY  on par_id=HISTORY.Pat_id
inner join Treatment  on par_id=Treatment.Pat_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It is too simple in mysql

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM PATIENT as p
LEFT JOIN HISTORY as h ON h.Pat_id = p.Pat_Id
LEFT JOIN Treatment as t ON t.His_id = h.His_Id
```