# Using multiple inner joins and sorting result

Tags: sql

In my DB there are three tables. I am trying to figure out how to List the school name, class name and teacher's name. Sort the records by class name within school name. I have a query but it is not working. How can I list the school name, class name and teacher's name and sort record by class name within school name?

```
SELECT c.class_name FROM class c INNER JOIN teacher t WHERE t.teacher_id = c.teacher_id INNER JOIN school s WHERE t.school_id = s.school_id;
```

TABLES

```
SQL> select * from class;

  CLASS_ID CLASS_NAME          TEACHER_ID MAX_SEATS_AVAILABLE
---------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Intro to ALGEBRA            11                  12
         2 Basic CALCULUS               2                  10
         3 ABC and 123                  1                  15
         4 Sharing 101                  8                  10
         5 Good Talk, Bad Talk          9                  20
         6 Nap Time                     1                  21
         7 WRITing 101                  5                  10
         8 Finger Painting              9                  14
         9 Physics 230                  2                  20
        10 Gym                          5                  25

10 rows selected.

SQL> select * from teacher;

TEACHER_ID FIRST_NAME       LAST_NAME        T HOME_ROOM_NUM PHONE_NUM  START_DAT HO  SCHOOL_ID
---------- ---------------- ---------------- - ------------- ---------- --------- -- ----------
         1 FRanK            JOHNSON          k 10C                      22-OCT-97 In      11090
         2 LISA             JONES            h 11Bc          317-587-90 19-JAN-15 iN     123134
                                                             87

         3 Jeff             Dafferty         C W8CZ                     12-DEC-96 OH      11546
         4 Frank            MARTIN           g 12aA          212-098-98 19-JAN-15 IN      11090
                                                             76

         5 John             Smith            H 34C                      10-OCT-93 In     123134
         6 John             Smith            G 34C                      10-OCT-93 in      11090
         7 Lisa             Jones            G 11E           317-587-90 19-JAN-15 IN     123134
                                                             87

         8 Trevor           Horse            k x                        19-JAN-15 Oh      11090
         9 Gregor           Ivan             K 12A           317-987-09 10-NOV-96 KY      11090
                                                             87

        10 Gregor           Ivan             g 12A           317-987-09 10-NOV-96 Ky      11090
                                                             87

        11 Pat              Francis          H 1z1a          123-317-09 19-JAN-15 Il      11546
                                                             12

        12 Brad             Smith            G 13A                      18-NOV-94 IN      11546

12 rows selected.

SQL> select * from school;

 SCHOOL_ID SCHOOL_NAME                   SCHOOL_TYPE
---------- ----------------------------- ------------
     11546 Ivy Tech College              COLLegE
     11090 LAWRENCE Central Grade School GRADE SCHOOL
     11111 Lawrence NORTH High School    HIGH SCHooL
     19283 Howe High SCHOOL              High SchooL
    123134 Lawrence Central High School  HIGH SCHOOL
       192 Little Big Horn Grade School  GRADE SCHOOL
```

Comment: What is your DataBase? MS SQL or Oracle or MySQL? What is your expected result from this? Can you please post that also.

Comment: Does your query even run ?

Comment: @SelvaTS oracle sql, ok will update

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254597/inner-join-three-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `join` to get what you want. This will give the all schools with the teachers and there classes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   sc.SCHOOL_NAME,
   teach.FIRST_NAME,
   teach.LAST_NAME ,
   cs.CLASS_NAME
FROM 
   school sc JOIN teacher teach
      ON sc.SCHOOL_ID = teach.SCHOOL_ID
   JOIN class cs ON cs.TEACHER_ID = teach.TEACHER_ID 
ORDER BY
     sc.SCHOOL_NAME,cs.CLASS_NAME
```

Comment: Ok, this what I need. I was not sure of how to structure the `JOINS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.FIRST_NAME +' '+t.LAST_NAME, s.SCHOOL_NAME, c.class_name
FROM class c 
INNER JOIN teacher t 
ON t.teacher_id = c.teacher_id 
INNER JOIN school s 
ON t.school_id = s.school_id
ORDER BY  s.SCHOOL_NAME,c.CLASS_NAME
```